# python pandas - calculate percentage change using last non-na value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am pretty new to python (mostly I use R) and I would like to perform a simple calculation but keep getting errors and incorrect results. I would like to calculate the percentage change for a column in a pandas df using the latest non-na value.  A toy example is below.

```
price = ['Nan', 10, 13, 'NaN', 'NaN', 9]
df = pd.DataFrame(price, columns = ['price'])
df['price_chg'] = df.price.pct_change(periods = -1)
```

I keep getting a weird result:

```
price_chg = [Nan, -0.2307, 0, 0, 0.4444, NaN]
```

I guess this has to do with the Nan values.  How do I tell python to use the latest non-na value.  The desired result is as follows:

```
price_chg = [Nan, -0.2307, 0.4444, 0, 0, NaN]
```

Since I don't know very much python at all, any suggestions would be welcome, even more convoluted ones.

Comment: `pd.to_numeric(df.price, errors='coerce').pct_change(periods = -1)`

Comment: @coldspeed what if `price` is already numeric?  I tried this solution on a different df and it didn't work.  perhaps I put up the wrong toy example

Comment: It is numeric. But the goal here is to coerce the strings 'NaN' to np.nan (actual NaN object).

Comment: @coldspeed sorry just changed code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is to employ backfill when calling the `pct_change` function.

`df['price_chg'] = df.price.pct_change(periods = -1, fill_method='backfill')`

This results in:

```
1   -0.230769
2    0.444444
3    0.000000
4    0.000000
5         NaN
```

[This page](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html#pandas.DataFrame.pct_change) describes the options you have when calling `pct_change`, including the `fill_method`.
You can learn more about the fill methods available in pandas [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#filling-missing-values-fillna)